# AngularJS directive data binding

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to control the visibility of a directive by passing boolean through an attribute and assigning that back to ng-show.

I have the following markup:

```
  <div>
      {{ showFromDate }}
      <input type="datetime" ng-click="showFromDate =!showFromDate" ng-model="fromDate"/>
      <simple-date-picker class="date-picker"  visibility="showFromDate" ng-show="popupVisible"  data-ng-model="fromDate">
          <p>This is a custom date picker</p>
       </simple-date-picker>
  </div>
```

and my angularjs code is :

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.directive('simpleDatePicker', ['$document', '$parse', function ($document, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            },
            scope: {
                visibility: "="
                },
           controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {

                        $scope.popupVisible = $scope.visibility;
                        $scope.showPopup = function($event) {
                            $event.stopPropagation()
                            $scope.popupVisible = true;
                          };
            }]
        };
    }]);
```

The issue I am having is, in the directive I can't retrieve the value of 'visibility' so I can assign it to $scope.popupVisible, which in turn gets passed to ng-show.

When I change ng-show to ng-show="showFromDate", I am able to show and hide the directive using the input's click handler. Example:

```
  <div>
  {{ showFromDate }}
   <input type="datetime" ng-click="showFromDate =!showFromDate" ng-model="fromDate"/>
            <simple-date-picker class="date-picker"  visibility="showFromDate" ng-show="showFromDate"  data-ng-model="fromDate">
            <p>This is a custom date picker</p>
            </simple-date-picker>
  </div>
```

My question is, how do I pass showFromDate to popupVisible?

Please note I want to do this because I will have multiple instances of the directive on the screen and each needs to be controlled individually.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass `visibility="popupVisible"` on your directive attribute instead of passing `showFromDate`

```
  <simple-date-picker class="date-picker"  visibility="popupVisible" ng-show="popupVisible"  data-ng-model="fromDate">
      <p>This is a custom date picker</p>
   </simple-date-picker>
```

Then there is not need of `$scope.popupVisible = $scope.visibility;` this line in directive controller

**OR**

Otherwise you need to only change `$scope.popupVisible = $scope.visibility;` line to `$scope.$parent.popupVisible = $scope.visibility;` that would change the value of parent controller, but is seems not good way of dealing with scopes.

The better approach would be pass one more value inside a directive isolated scope. & do play with it like currently you are doing with `visibility: "="`